# Can we use Tiers of DMG for 3 Pillars Experience System?

Tags: dnd-5e, experience-points, unearthed-arcana

Unearthed Arcana provides a new possibility of granting experience: [Three-Pillars Experience](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/3pillarxp)

This system is based on tiers (see page 2 1st paragraph). The only part I can find any explanation of tiers in 5e is in the DMG.

- Tier 1: 1-4
- Tier 2: 5-10
- Tier 3: 11-16
- Tier 4: 17-20

Are these the tiers used in the new experience system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, those are the tiers being referenced.

They're primarily described on p.15 of the PHB. You'll also find them mentioned in many modules written for Adventurers League, and you may notice that they are the levels at which damaging cantrips scale up.

Comment: Some Cantrips increase in damage. And if they do they do it at level 5, 11 and 17. Thanks for that awesome answer.